# Why only script-src unsafe-inline is reported as a high severity finding?

Tags: content-security-policy

I'm evaluating a CSP policy using https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/. The policy is configured as follow:

```
default-src 'self';object-src 'self';script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';script-src-attr 'self' 'unsafe-inline';
```

Why only `'unsafe-inline'` of `'script-src'` is reported as a high severity finding? From what I understood also `'script-src-elem' 'unsafe-inline'` could be dangerous. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you are missing anything, this does seem to be an error in googles CSP evaluator.

`script-src-elem` [is used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src-elem) to control the source of `script` tags (inline or external; see also the [spec](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#directive-script-src-elem)). You can test this yourself, eg with:

```
<?php
header("content-security-policy: script-src 'self'; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline'")
?>
<script>alert(1);</script>
```

Viewed with Chrome, the payload will fire (Firefox does not support `script-src-elem`). If you remove `unsafe-inline`, the CSP will block the script.

So we can see that `script-src-elem 'unsafe-inline'` is indeed dangerous.

Comment: of course, by "dangerous" we mean "not any safer than the default, so why are you using this safety feature at all?"

Answer (score 1):

> Why only 'unsafe-inline' of 'script-src' is reported as a high
> severity finding? From what I understood also 'script-src-elem'
> 'unsafe-inline' could be dangerous

This is not a mistake, Google is doing it deliberately.

**I)**. 'unsafe-inline' has three attack vectors:

1. inline blocks `<script></script>`
2. javascript navigation like `<a href='javascript: ...'>` and `<iframe src='javascript: ...'>`
3. inline event handlers in tags like `<tag onClick='javascript here'>`

Rules `script-src-elem 'unsafe-inline'` is **really safer** than `script-src 'unsafe-inline'`, since it reduces the number of attack vectors from 3 to one.
Besides, "classic" XSS with `<script></script>` insertion is a rarity, webmasters no longer make such childish mistakes.
The most common XSS is with insufficient escaping of quotes and injecting tags with `onclick='...'` attributes and `script-src-elem 'unsafe-inline'` defends from those.

**II)**. If you do a little research of `csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com`, you will realize that this is more of an **educational toy** than a real test of CSP safety.
Google csp-evaluator simply reacts to familiar words or their absence, it does not performs check of CSP rules with relation to each other. For example `script-src 'unsafe-inline'; sandbox;` will trigger 'High severity finding' in scripts, although `sandbox ;` rule completely disallows all scripts.

`csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com` this is more a "political" move then real vulnerability checker. Google just educates webmasters to make attention to some common mistakes and tries at the subconscious level to consolidate the idea that Chrome is safer than others.

**PS:** The `script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'` rule is wrong, `'unsafe-eval'` [is not supported](https://csplite.com/csp/test345/) in the `script-src-elem` directive. But `csp-evaluator` keeps a silent abt this.